# How do I properly implement Textbox Validation

Tags: wpf, validation, c#-4.0, mvvm, data-binding

I am new to WPF and creating an application which as few text boxes. Text boxes are bound to some source using MVVM. Now when I click on save button, it should fire validation for all empty text boxes and save event should not be fired. How can I achieve this in WPF.

I have written validater but it is not called. See my code below:

```
<TextBox Width="250" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="ContinuousModel.FileName" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validate:RequiredFieldValidatation />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>


public class RequiredFieldValidatation:ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (value == null || value.ToString() == string.Empty)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Value cannot be empty");
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

The above validator is getting called only if some text is written then change focus then come back and remove value and then change focus.

**NOTE**: Using MVVM and datatemplates, I am loading varios user controls and those controls are bound to viewmodel. Save button is in different user control so I cannot validate all text boxes manually on save button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Add the UpdateSourceTrigger property to your binding;

```
<Binding Path="ContinuousModel.FileName" UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validate:RequiredFieldValidatation />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
```